# I want to display an image instead of downloading it (Image in database blob)

Tags: php

I want display an image instead of downloading it.

I have image in my database table, column as BLOB.

This snippet downloads the image, but I want to display it instead:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM upload";
$result  = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$content =  $row['content'];
$size =  $row['size'];
$type =  $row['type'];
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");

// The following headers make the image download, but I don't want it to
// download, I want to show the image. What should I do?
// header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");

echo $content;
```

Comment: Your code should work as is, since you've commented out the "Content-Disposition" line. What really matters is the "Content-Type" header. You should make sure that this contains something like "image/jpeg" so the browser knows it's an image.

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache? Happens all the time with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use this more dynamically make a script of your original code and call it like this:

```
<img src="image.php?imageid=$myImageID" />
```

and your script is:

```
$myImageID = $_GET["myImageID"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM upload where id='"+$myImageID+"'";
$result  = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$content =  $row['content'];
$size =  $row['size'];
$type =  $row['type'];
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");---> this headers make system to download , but i dont want to download, i want to show image, what  should i do ,
echo $content; ?>"
```

Comment: the above snippet now working, instead showing image, it just showing path like http://localhost/source/iq/upload-file-mysql.php

Comment: if your php code is not correct your image is not shown, and if you access let's say the image.php?imageId =$myImageID in a browser you should see your image

Comment: this code is extremly dangerous! don't you know never to trust user input? this is a sure way to get a SQL injection!

Answer (score 7):

The opposite content-disposition of `attachment` is `inline`. Try this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$name");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to be sure nothing else than your headers and the image content is sent to the client. maybe you want to do an exit after echo $content; this is not a best practice and also does not ensure that nothing else has been sent before you output the image content, but it should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

You can display the image instead of downloading it with this code:

```
<a href="myimage.png">Click to download</a>
```